# React Native Qualtrics SDK not compiling `CompileC` command failing. ARC Semantic Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, qualtrics

After following the instructions in the [api documentation](https://api.qualtrics.com/sdks/ZG9jOjgwNTgzNjM-getting-started-with-react-native-sdk), I am having trouble installing and compiling the Qualtrics React Native SDK.

I’ve done what Qualtrics Support suggested (set react-native-qualtrics to 2.0 in package.json and set Qualtrics dependency to “~>2.2.0” in my Podfile) and encountered a similar error, though some of the other errors appear to have been fixed.

This is the only error I am now receiving for iOS. I have not adjusted the Android build yet because I am focusing on one platform at a time.

```
** BUILD FAILED **The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/isaiahpettingill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/smi-fgrvefjrqjgedicqzieveuytuvme/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNQualtricsDigital.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNQualtricsDigital.o /Users/isaiahpettingill/Documents/GitHub/phoenix_mobile_app_2/node_modules/react-native-qualtrics/ios/RNQualtricsDigital.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

This tells me that somehow one of the Objective-C Class Implementation files (`RNQualtricsDigital.m`) that are shipped with the SDK fails to compile. My guess is that I likely have a dependency conflict of some kind, although I do not know the internal workings of the Qualtrics SDK, nor am I an experienced Objective-C developer.

I've made sure that Flipper is disabled.

My react native version is 0.64.2, XCode version is 12.4, Podfile target iOS version 11, node version 12.x

I am compiling using `yarn ios` in a react-native-cli (no expo) project.

When I compile from XCode onto a device, I get the following error:

```
No visible @interface for 'Qualtrics' declares the selector 'initializeProjectWithBrandId:projectId:completion:'
```

on the following lines of code in the shipped RNQualtricsDigital.m

```
//line 168
BOOL displayResult = [Qualtrics.shared displayInterceptFor:interceptId viewController:rootViewController];
```

```
//line 24
[Qualtrics.shared initializeProjectWithBrandId:brandId projectId:zoneId completion:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,InitializationResult *> * _Nonnull result) {
        //... implementation
}
```

I'd appreciate seeing a working implementation of the SDK and/or a solution/suggestions for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover how to make this work.

I reached out to Qualtrics support, and they sent me a working example of implementing version 2.2 of the React Native SDK. I was able to build it and run it and find out what my issue was.

I had misunderstood the original package configuration.
If you configure your packages this way, it will build and run.

package.json

```json
"react-native-qualtrics": "2.2.0"
```

Podfile

```rb
    pod 'Qualtrics', '~> 2.1.0'
```

[this repo](https://github.com/Deadlatin/SDK-react-native) contains the working example provided by Qualtrics Support. If anyone has a similar issue, this is a great starting point because it proves that it can be done. Note: to get it working, you may need to clean node modules and pods, and run an xcode clean before reinstalling all dependencies and building.